# Insert empty string into INT column for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, insert, numeric

A `SAMPLE` table has only one column `ID` of type `int`, default null.

In Oracle when I do:

```
  insert into SAMPLE (ID) values ('');
```

the new record is added with blank value. But in SQL Server 2008, when I run the same `insert` statement, the new record has the value of 0.

Is there a way to force SQL Server 2008 to default blank string to NULL instead of 0 (for numerical type of columns)?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that your INSERT statement is part of a stored procedure re-used in many places of your application (or, perhaps, is a batch always constructed by the same part of the client code) and that the inserted value is a number passed as a string argument, you could modify the INSERT like this:

```
INSERT INTO SAMPLE (ID) VALUES (NULLIF(@argument, ''));
```

Answer (score 6):

Use NULL instead.

```
insert into SAMPLE (ID) values (NULL);
```

Comment: I know the NULL will work. But I have to change a LOT of code what works perfectly with Oracle, not to mention a LOT of testing too. :(

Comment: I don't think you can do this without modifying your code. I know of no setting in that will make SQL Server treat empty string as NULL.

Answer (score 4):

How about another idea - define an [INSTEAD OF INSERT Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Despite the fact that you're trying to insert a string, with this the operation is "intercepted", empty string is replaced by NULL, and the insert succeeds.

If you define this trigger on your table, then you can continue to insert empty string as before, with no other changes.

**Edit:** As Martin Smith points out, this effectively is a comparison to 0 (the equivalent of empty string as an int) meaning you won't be able to store 0 in this table. I leave this answer here in case that's acceptable to your situation - either that or re-do all your queries!

```
CREATE TRIGGER EmptyStringTrigger
ON [SAMPLE]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO [SAMPLE](ID)
      SELECT CASE
               WHEN ID = '' THEN NULL
               ELSE ID
             END
      FROM   inserted
  END
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8ec9/2)

Comment: That will also convert all zeros to `NULL`. The cast of empty string to zero happens first so that `ID` in `inserted` is the correct datatype then your comparison `WHEN ID = '' THEN NULL` does another implicit cast from `''` to `0` for the string literal there so you are effectively doing `WHEN ID = 0 THEN NULL`

Comment: @MartinSmith Good point, I hadn't noticed that. I can't think of a way around that. I will leave this answer here in case this is acceptable for OP's situation anyway.

Comment: @MartinSmith I've edited to include your point. And there I was wondering why no-one else had suggested it, if it was that simple! Thanks for your valuable insights as always.

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert a 'string' into a int column. Oracle must be just handling that for you.

Just try inserting NULL if that's what you need.

```
insert into SAMPLE (ID) values (NULL);
```

Comment: insert into SAMPLE (ID) values ('5'); I get ID=5, Oracle and SQL server are doing the same

insert into SAMPLE (ID) values (''); I get ID=0 for SQL server, and '' for Oracle

Comment: In Oracle empty strings and `Null` are synonomous I believe.

Answer (score 0):

One more option

```
insert into SAMPLE (ID) values (DEFAULT)
```