# SQL Server DB Project Publish Empty string inserting a Zero

Tags: sql-server, publish, default-value, varchar

We are seeing a very strange problem when populating a field in a DB via a SQL Server DB project publish action.

This is the table definition

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CatalogueItemExtensionFields] 
(
    [RowID] tinyint identity not null,
    [FieldType] tinyint not null,
    [Description] varchar(120) not null,
    [Nullable] bit not null,
    [DefaultValue] varchar(100) null,
    [Active_Flag] bit null,
    [OrderPriority] tinyint not null,
    [ContextGuid] uniqueidentifier not null
);
```

This is the population script

```
set identity_insert CatalogueItemExtensionFields on

INSERT INTO CatalogueItemExtensionFields (rowid, fieldtype, description, nullable, defaultvalue, active_flag, orderpriority) 
VALUES (dbo.ConstantProductGroupRowId(), 3, 'Product Group', 0, '', 1, dbo.ConstantProductGroupRowId()),

set identity_insert CatalogueItemExtensionFields off
```

If I run the `INSERT` script manually all works fine. When I run it as part of the DB project publish, it inserts "0".

I have looked at the `publish.sql` script that is generated, and all looks fine.

BTW, the only similar post I have found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189688/insert-empty-string-into-int-column-for-sql-server), but it does not apply to our case because the field we are inserting into is defined as varchar.

This is driving us mad. Any ideas?

Comment: Inserts 0 where? There are 8 columns there. I believe these scripts are run in SQLCMD mode. So set SSMS to SQLCMD mode and see if it does the same thing (inserts '0'). What does it do when it works properly? Is `dbo.ConstantProductGroupRowId()` a user defined scalar function? What does it look like?

Comment: Just to clarify, I am trying to insert the empty string into the "defaultvalue" column.

Comment: @NickMcDermaid, we just tried running the publish script in SQLCMD mode and got this error when trying to write a valid string: 'Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 7 Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'test' to data type int.' So this means that the SQLCMD thinks the field is an INT, but that is not how it appears in the table definition. Is there any obscure DB setting used in SQLCMD mode?

Comment: I don't see the word 'test' in your sample script. I also see an additonal unneeded trailing comma in your `VALUES` clause. This is all very confusing. Do you have any triggers on this table? Is this the only script you are running? What does dbo.ConstantProductGroupRowId() do? Does it return a string or a number?

Answer (score 1):

We at our company finally found out that if you use SQLCMD / DBProj then it is super import to ENABLE Quoted Identifiers. Or else installer changes inputs in the exactly same way as @maurocam explained. If you enable this, then it works same as in SQL Management Studio for example.

**To enable it:**

- SQLCMD

  - just use parameter -I (capital is important here, small is for file).
  - Example `sqlcmd -S localhost -d DBNAME -U User -P Password -i path/to/sql/file.sql -I`
- SQL Itself

  - `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER { ON | OFF }`
- DBProj

  - can be set at the project or object (proc, func, ...) level. Just click on a proj/file -> Properties and check if QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is enabled there.
  - For schema compare it can be set via "Ignore quoted identifiers"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

APOLOGIES - MY MISTAKE!!! (**But a very useful one to document**)

I have summarised again below (also to make it clearer respect to my initial post)

TABLE DEFINITION

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CatalogueItemExtensionFields] 
(
[RowID] tinyint identity not null,
[FieldType] tinyint not null,
[Description] varchar(120) not null,
[Nullable] bit not null,
[DefaultValue] varchar(100) null,
[Active_Flag] bit null,
[OrderPriority] tinyint not null
);
```

INSERT STATEMENT

```
set identity_insert CatalogueItemExtensionFields on

INSERT INTO CatalogueItemExtensionFields (rowid, fieldtype, description, nullable, defaultvalue, active_flag, orderpriority) VALUES
(6, 3, N'Product Group', 0, N'', 1, 6),
(7, 2, N'Minimum Order Quantity', 1, NULL, 1, 7),
(8, 3, N'Additional HIBCs', 0, 1, 1, 8),
(9, 3, N'Additional GTINs', 0, N'', 1, 9)

set identity_insert CatalogueItemExtensionFields off
```

Because I am inserting multiple rows, when SQL parses the statement it see I am trying to insert a numeric defaultvalue = 1 for RowID = 8. As a result, even though the column is defined as a varchar, SQL decides that the INSERT statement is inserting INTs. So the empty string values (for RowIDs 7 and 9) are converted to zero. I referred to a post I had found relating to [actual INT column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189688/insert-empty-string-into-int-column-for-sql-server), which results in the same behaviour.

If I instead run the following statement, with a default value of '1' for RowID = 8, it all works fine.

```
INSERT INTO CatalogueItemExtensionFields (rowid, fieldtype, description, nullable, defaultvalue, active_flag, orderpriority) VALUES
(6, 3, N'Product Group', 0, N'', 1, 6),
(7, 2, N'Minimum Order Quantity', 1, NULL, 1, 7),
(8, 3, N'Additional HIBCs', 0, '1', 1, 8),
(9, 3, N'Additional GTINs', 0, N'', 1, 9)
```

So, now the question is, why does SQL server ignore the column type definition and instead decides the type from the value in my INSERT statement?

Answer (score 0):

[Answer from SqlServerCentral](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1655898/DB-Project-Publish-Empty-string-inserting-a-Zero#bm1662197)

"empty string converts to an int without an error, and it's value is zero. it has to do with the precidence of implicit conversions"