# NULL values not inserted with create()

Tags: php, laravel

I have this field in the form:

```
 <label>Office Phone:</label><br>
 <input type="number" name="office_phone"  value="{{ old('office_phone') }}" class="form-control"><br>
    @if ($errors->has('office_phone'))
               <span class="help-block">
                      <strong>{{ $errors->first('office_phone') }}</strong>
               </span>
    @endif
```

This is not a required field. It is supposed to insert Null values in database if not any input is given.

I have this validation rule:

```
  'office_phone'=>'integer',
```

And create() method :

```
return User::create([
   'office_phone'=>$data['office_phone]
```

But Null value is not inserted if no input is given: it gives error:

> Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column
>   'office_phone' at row 1

But if `office_phone` has some value, it is inserted fine. What am i doing wrong?

```
office_phone in database has Type int(10) default NULL and Null yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case what is happening when no value then its passing empty string `''` which is empty value in MYSQL. So it throwing this error as for integer column such value not allowed but for varchar its fine.

So you have two options:

- Either change in mysql to set default as 0
- check in PHP side if its empty send NULL or 0 to DB.

For more Reference:
[Insert empty string into INT column for SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189688/insert-empty-string-into-int-column-for-sql-server)

[How to allow empty string for integer in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606483/how-to-allow-empty-string-for-integer-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

If you not enter data then your value will be blank and `"" != NULL`. So if value is blank replace it with null. Try this:(before `return User::create()`)

```
$data['office_phone'] = $data['office_phone'] === ""?NULL:$data['office_phone'];
```