# Why does an int column values defaults to '0' when passed empty?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have table with an integer column.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tble1](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [test] [nchar](10) NULL
)
```

When I try to insert some values and pass an empty string to the id column like below, it gets inserted and the value of the id column is 0 by default.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tble1]
       ([id],[test])
 VALUES
       ('','a')
```

I couldn't find any satisfying reasoning behind it. Could some one please share your thoughts on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert empty string into INT column for SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189688/insert-empty-string-into-int-column-for-sql-server)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is happening is that `''` is being converted to an integer.  The rules are that a string can be converted, based on the digit characters in the string.

If a string is empty, it gets converted to 0.

So, the conversion is happening at the very "top" level.  The types don't match so SQL Server attempts an implicit conversion.

Unfortunately, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql) is not really clear on the topic:

> Character expressions that are being converted to an exact numeric
>   data type must consist of digits, a decimal point, and an optional
>   plus (+) or minus (-). Leading blanks are ignored. Comma separators,
>   such as the thousands separator in 123,456.00, are not allowed in the
>   string.

To be honest, I would interpret the "must consist of digits" as saying that there must be at least one digit (although technically in English "zero" is treated as a plural, I don't necessarily think of plurals as including zero elements).  However, the empty string has been used -- pretty much for forever -- as a valid value for any type across a broad range of databases.

Answer (score 0):

It will try to Convert ' ' to Integer and it got succeeded.

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, '')
```

Output

```
0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting defaulted value to 0, as you have NOT null, defined for the column,
if you keep ID as null, then it will put NULL,

Also, if you want to populate the value automatically then you set the  identity for the column