# How to insert empty string (' ') to decimal or numeric in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, decimal, numeric

Is there a way to insert an empty string (' ') into a column of type `decimal`?

This is for the example :

```
create table #temp_table 
(
    id varchar(8) NULL,
    model varchar(20) NULL,
    Plandate date NULL,
    plan_qty decimal (18, 0) NULL,
    Remark varchar (50) NULL,
)

insert into #temp_table (id, model, Plandate, plan_qty, Remark)
values ('pn-01', 'model-01', '2017-04-01', '', 'Fresh And Manual')
```

I get an error

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

My data is from an Excel file and has some blank cells.

My query read that as an empty string.

If there is a way, please help.

Thanks

Comment: What are you using to insert the data from an Excel file to your Table?

Comment: I use Bulk Copy to a temporary table and then insert the data to destination table. My query used by my developer in VB.Net and get error while compiling. but its already resolved. thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based off your comments you just need a case statement to your insert from excel, which I assume is using open query or bulk insert.

```
Insert into #temp_table (id, model, Plandate, plan_qty, Remark)
Select
...
Case when someColumn = '' then null else someColumn end
...
From
--your excel file via openquery or whatever ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert an empty *string* into a numeric field.  You can insert `NULL`:

```
insert into #temp_table (id, model, Plandate, plan_qty, Remark)
    values ('112325', '10TPB220MC', '2017-04-01', NULL, 'Fresh And Manual');
```

Of course, the default default value is `NULL`, so you can also just leave it out:

```
insert into #temp_table (id, model, Plandate, Remark)
    values ('112325', '10TPB220MC', '2017-04-01', 'Fresh And Manual');
```

Comment: thank you, I have try this one and this is OK. but my data is from excel file and there is blank cell and my query read it as empty string.

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned, could insert NULL instead of empty string so one more option is to use [NULLIF](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_nullif.asp). In your case:

```
insert into #temp_table (id, model, Plandate, plan_qty, Remark)
values ('pn-01', 'model-01', '2017-04-01', NULLIF(value_which_may_be_empty, ''), 'Fresh And Manual')
```

Related: [Insert empty string into INT column for SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13189688/5962766)